# Sails JS model attribute issue

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Either I have broken something or miss-understood how sails works
Using the API anyone can put or post to any model information that is not designed to be there, or atleast in my experience.
Am I missing a setting that discards any attributes that someone attempts to add if they do not fit the model structure?

I have a model that is entirely blank, I simply post `aa=aa` and suddenly I this

```
{
  "aa": "aa",
  "createdAt": "2016-05-03T03:55:56.977Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-05-03T03:55:56.977Z",
  "id": 2
}
```

Surely I will not have to write a policy that checks every incoming requests of invalid parameters...

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the setting `schema` in the `model.js` file needs to be set to `true` for this sort of behavior.